# ¿Cómo puedo preguntar si una conexión a base de datos fue exitosa o fracasó?

Tags: php, base-de-datos, laravel-8, timeout, conexión

Buen día.
Estoy trabajando en laravel 8 y estoy usando dos bases de datos(Base de datos A y base de datos B). Para la base de datos A, hay que acceder solo mediante cable de red y, además, podría ser que en algún momento esta conexión no se pueda llevar a cabo. Por esto, debo preguntar "Si la conexion a la base de datos fue exitosa, entonces usaré la base de datos A, sino usaré la base de datos B"(La conexión a b es 100% efectiva).
Para hacer lo anterior, intenté un par de cosas. Entre ellas está esta opción que me parece la mejor(Foto 1). Si la conexión fue exitosa escribe "Conexión exitosa", pero si no fue exitosa, en vez de escribir "Se usará la segunda base de datos", me tira un mensaje de error(Foto 2).
Con todo lo anterior, mi pregunta es ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que ejecute ciertas instrucciones si es que no hay conexión, en vez de que salga el mensaje de error?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El código debe ir en formato texto y no como imagen. Te invito a leer [ask] y [mcve]. Saludos

Comment: Que utilizas? Query builder o Eloquent? Ademas, donde estas poniendo ese codigo

Comment: Por otro lado, las excepciones se manejan en un bloque [`try catch`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.exceptions.php). Un bloque `if else` no te sirve para el propósito buscado. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras [odbc_connect](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.odbc-connect.php) devuelve `false` si ocurre un error

Comment: Pues la imagen muestra una excepción no controlada, las excepciones se manejan con `try catch`. No sé dónde estaría el problema ya que la pregunta es deficiente. No está demás que use un bloque `try catch`. Pero sin más información por parte del OP, es difícil saber dónde estaría el fallo.

Comment: Y por qué si usas Laravel manejas así las conexiones?